# How to count the numbers of A's, B's, C's, D's and F's in average score calculator?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am attempting to write a Python script that calculates the average score and the numbers of A's, B's, C's, D's and F's from a user input number of exams and exam scores.

I've tried a variety of methods for the part of the script currently in the function: 
"def letter_score(scores):"
but have had no success with being able to assign the input exam grades with their corresponding letters.

```
    sum_of_scores = 0
    number_of_exams = int(input("What is the size of the class? "))
    print("Now enter the scores below.")
    for i in range(1, number_of_exams + 1):
     scores = int(input("Student %d : " %(i)))
     sum_of_scores += scores

    def letter_score(scores):
      if scores >= 90:
        scores = "A"
      elif scores < 90 and scores >= 80:
        scores = "B"
      elif scores < 80 and scores >= 70:
        scores = "C"
      elif scores < 70 and scores >= 60:
        scores = "D"
      else:
        scores = "F"

    average_score = sum_of_scores/number_of_exams

    print("The average is " + str(average_score))

    print("There are " + str(scores) + " A's.")
    print("There are " + str(scores) + " B's.")
    print("There are " + str(scores) + " C's.")
    print("There are " + str(scores) + " D's.")
    print("There are " + str(scores) + " F's.")
```

I was successful in finding the average score, but the letter grades are giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store the count of letter_score

You can initialize the dictionary with all 0 by:

```py
letter_score_count = { "A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "F": 0}
```

Give return value in the function `letter_score` using `return` keyword

```py
    def letter_score(scores):
        if scores >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif scores < 90 and scores >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif scores < 80 and scores >= 70:
            return "C"
        elif scores < 70 and scores >= 60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return"F"
```

By then, call the `letter_score` method, use the result as the key of dictionary to increase the counter of each letter score when inputting the scores

```py
letter_score_count[letter_score(scores)] += 1
```

In the end, you can print the result

```py
print("There are " + str(letter_score_count["A"]) + " A's.")
```

The edited version from your code. Hope this help

```py
    sum_of_scores = 0
    number_of_exams = int(input("What is the size of the class? "))
    print("Now enter the scores below.")
    letter_score_count = { "A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "F": 0}
    def letter_score(scores):
        if scores >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif scores < 90 and scores >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif scores < 80 and scores >= 70:
            return "C"
        elif scores < 70 and scores >= 60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return"F"

    for i in range(1, number_of_exams + 1):
        scores = int(input("Student %d : " % (i)))
        sum_of_scores += scores
        letter_score_count[letter_score(scores)] += 1

    average_score = sum_of_scores / number_of_exams

    print("The average is " + str(average_score))

    print("There are " + str(letter_score_count["A"]) + " A's.")
    print("There are " + str(letter_score_count["B"]) + " B's.")
    print("There are " + str(letter_score_count["C"]) + " C's.")
    print("There are " + str(letter_score_count["D"]) + " D's.")
    print("There are " + str(letter_score_count["F"]) + " F's.")
```

Comment: build a list and then use a `collections.Counter` object instead of incrementing a dictionary https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps. You need to include count logic in your letter score function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def letter_score(scores,counter_store):
      if scores >= 90:
           scores = "A"
           counter_store["A"]+=1
      elif scores < 90 and scores >= 80:
           scores = "B"
           counter_store["B"]+=1
      elif scores < 80 and scores >= 70:
           scores = "C"
           counter_store["C"]+=1
      elif scores < 70 and scores >= 60:
           scores = "D"
           counter_store["D"]+=1
      else:
           scores = "F"
           counter_store["F"]+=1
      return(counter_store)
sum_of_scores = 0
counter_store=defaultdict(int)
number_of_exams = int(input("What is the size of the class? "))
print("Now enter the scores below.")
for i in range(1, number_of_exams + 1):
     scores = int(input("Student %d : " %(i)))
     score_count=letter_score(scores,counter_store)
     sum_of_scores += scores


average_score = sum_of_scores/number_of_exams
print("The average is " + str(average_score))

print("There are " + str(counter_store["A"]) + " A's.")
print("There are " + str(counter_store["B"]) + " B's.")
print("There are " + str(counter_store["C"]) + " C's.")
print("There are " + str(counter_store["D"]) + " D's.")
print("There are " + str(counter_store["F"]) + " F's.")
```